# How to save input by pointing to string array?

Tags: c, pointers

Here I want to save input string by pointing to an array, but the output will all change to the last inserted input.

```
char **month;
int row, col;
int i, j;
char name[10];

month = (char **)malloc(3*sizeof(char *));

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    month[i] = (char *)malloc(10*sizeof(char));

    printf("Enter name\n");

    scanf("%s", name);

    month[i] = name;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    printf("%s\n", month[i]);
}

return 0;
```

Any idea how can I fix it?

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of malloc() and family in C..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Comment: FYI: `sizeof(char)` is always 1. Also, there is no real benefit of allocating such a small memory. Just go with `char month[3][10]`.

Answer (score 2):

These two lines are problematic:

```
month[i] = (char *)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
...
month[i] = name;
```

The first allocates memory and makes `month[i]` point to that memory. The second line *reassigns* `month[i]` to make it point to `name` instead. You lose the original memory (and have a memory leak). Besides the memory leak it also means that *all* elements of `month` will point to the same memory, which will contain the last input read.

Instead of using assignment you could [*copy*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) the string:

```
strcpy(month[i], name);
```

Or skip the temporary `name` variable and read directly into `month[i]`:

```
scanf("%9s", month[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
month[i] = name;
```

to this:

```
strcpy(month[i], name);
```

since you need to use [`strcpy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) to copy/assign a string in C.

---

BTW: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) No.